# What am I doing wrong in this multiples While program?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * A program that will prompt the user to enter a number and

 * then print out all the multiples of that number that are less than 1000.
 * 
 */


import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.text.*;

public class Unit3_Lesson5_1

{

static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

public static void main() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

    DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("'$'0.00");    
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); 


int i, sum, num;
String start;

System.out.println("Hit Enter to begin!");

start = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter a number that you want the multiples of");

num = in.nextInt();

sum = 0;
while (sum < 1000)


    for (i=1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
     sum = num * i;
     System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

I'm trying to get this program to work but it keeps giving me all multiples, including ones over 1000 when I want it to not go over 1000. What am I doing wrong? I need to be using a While loop.

Comment: **java !== javascript**

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry I am new to programming and not fully understanding everything yet.

Comment: The condition of a `while` loop is tested immediately before each iteration, but not at any other time.  Your program updates variable `sum` many times between each such test.

Comment: Your main method is not looking good.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 loops in one, what is not necessary in this case. So use just one loop to achieve this:

If you want use `for` loop

> **NOTE**: for condition is checking `sum` value while increasing `i` variable.

```
for (i=1; sum <= 1000; i++)
{
 sum = num * i;
 System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Or if you want to use `do-while` loop

> **NOTE**: you must declare `i` counter before the loop in order to have a variable to increase.

```
int i = 0;

while (sum < 1000) {
   sum = num * i;
   i ++;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aeos if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if sum < 1000 in the for loop, so it will shoot past 1000 very quickly, and won't stop until the for loop is finished.  You should remove the for loop, and just increment i in the while loop.

Comment: I did this and it seems to be what I'm looking for, except for the fact that its going 1 multiple too high. For example it's outputtting:
300
600
900
1200

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one loop with an and condition:

```
for (i=1; i <= 100 && sum < 1000; i++) {
    sum = num * i;
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Like hotlc's reply, I still get one multiple over 1000 which is the 1200.

Comment: Yes, because you check that sum is less than 1000 and then you multiply again. If you want to avoid it, change the condition to `i <= 100 && num*i < 1000` and then it won't multiply it over 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of (sum < 1000) you should have (sum < (100 * num)).

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me all the multiples when I just need the ones under 1000.

Comment: ((sum < 1000) && (sum < (100 * num))

Answer (score 0):

take away your while loop and place an if statement inside your for loop with System.exit(0);

```
for (i=1; i <= 100; i++)
{
 sum = num * i;
 if(sum>1000){
 System.exit(0);
 }
 System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program , will run the "for" loop ( doesn't matter the value of "sum" ) before getting back to the "while" block . Remove the 'for' loop and increment "i" each iteration of the while block . 
Hope this help !

Comment: Yes, I have done this and unfortunately now, it keeps going one over the 1000 multiple.